# @JmsListener prevent message rollback if message not valid

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I use LocalValidatorFactoryBean and javax.validation annotations to validate my payload in @JmsListener.Is there any way to prevent message rollback if message is not valid and exception was thrown? Setting `ErrorHandler` to `ADTJmsListenerContainerFactory` is not a solution because the `ErrorHandler` is invoked after the rollback.

Here is my config:

OracleAQConfig:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableJms
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OracleAQConfig {
    private final ConnectionFactory receiverActiveMQConnectionFactory;

    @Bean(name = "jmsListenerFactory")
    public ADTJmsListenerContainerFactory orderADTJmsListenerContainerFactory(final ClobConverter clobConverter,
                                                                              final DatasourceProperties datasourceProperties,
                                                                              @Value("${listener.concurrency}") final String concurrency) {
        ADTJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
                new ADTJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(receiverActiveMQConnectionFactory);
        factory.setAutoStartup(true);
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        factory.setRecoveryInterval(datasourceProperties.getQueueRecoveryInterval());
        factory.setMessageConverter(clobConverter);
        factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

ADTJmsListenerContainerFactory:

```
public class ADTJmsListenerContainerFactory extends DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory {

    @Override
    protected DefaultMessageListenerContainer createContainerInstance() {
        return new AdtMessageListenerContainer();
    }

}
```

ActiveMQConfig:

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
public class ActiveMQConfig implements JmsListenerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setMessageHandlerMethodFactory(methodFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory methodFactory() {
        DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory factory = new DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
        factory.setValidator(validator());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

Listener:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class MyListener {

    @JmsListener(destination = "${queue.name}", containerFactory = "jmsListenerFactory")
    public void process(@Payload @Valid Pojo pojo, Session session) throws JMSException {
        log.info("New message from queue {}", pojo);

        try {
            //do smth
            session.commit();
        } catch (SpecificException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            session.rollback();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Pojo:

```
@Getter
public class Pojo {
    private String field1;

    @NotNull
    private String field2;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
2023-04-05 13:52:45.699 | DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2 | WARN  | o.s.data.jdbc.jms.listener.oracle.AdtMessageListenerContainer           - Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
        org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with incoming message
        Endpoint handler details:
        Method [public void mypackage.MyListener.process(mypackage.dto.POJO,javax.jms.Session) throws javax.jms.JMSException]
        Bean [mypackage.MyListener@7a572b4]
        ; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Could not resolve method parameter
```

Comment: Have you considered removing the @Valid annotation and performing the validation within the method?

Comment: @DwB yes, but i think that it would be prettier if I perform validation by annotations. I'm trying to avoid having the validation process appear in the listener method and leaving only the business logic there.